# Facebook asking about "Privacy Policy URL"

Tags: facebook

Help!

I can't seem to find the "privacy policy field" upon logging to developers facebook.

When I click on the URL they sent (http://developers.facebook.com/apps/XXXXXXXXXX/auth) and logged in with our admin account, it doesn't show "basic" setup, where I could find the "privacy policy field".

How can update the "privacy policy field"?

Answer (score 1):

You will find the privacy policy URL under `Edit Settings -> Auth Dialog`

Comment: please look at what i'm seeing upon clicking the link...http://dealspot.ph/facebook_app.jpg

Answer (score 1):

As @Yan said, you can find it in the Auth Dialog and in the Advanced Settings/Contact Info.